# Underlying topological space spectrum of tensor product with Burnside ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The motivation for this question comes from the following snippet from notes of Dress (sadly not easily available online):

[image]

Here $\Omega(G)$ denotes the [Burnside ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_ring). I'm having a little trouble interpreting Corollary P.5.2(3). Let me write $|X|$ for the underlying set of a scheme. Then he seems to be saying that that natural map
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
$$
|\Spec(S) \times_{\Spec(\mathbb{Z})} \Spec(\Omega(G))| \to |\Spec(S)| \times_{|Spec(\mathbb{Z})|} |\Spec(\Omega(G))|
$$
is a bijection. Moreover, the claim seems to be that this is true if I replace the ring $\Omega(G)$ with a ring $R$ with the property that for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in \Spec(R)$, the quotient ring $R/\frak{p}$ is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p$. Assuming I've interpreted the meaning correctly, how does one see this? Is there a reference? Finally, if it is true as sets, is it also true as topological spaces?

*Dress, Andreas W. M.*, Notes on the theory of representations of finite groups. Part I: The Burnside ring of a finite group and some AGN-applications. With the aid of lecture notes, taken by Manfred Küchler, Universität Bielefeld, Fakultät für Mathematik. 157, A 28, B 31 p. (1971). [ZBL0241.20042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0241.20042).